# Wordpress Stylesheet (child theme and theme) Editor Not updating on site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Ok, another dolt question from me. I edit the darn child theme stylesheet but it doesn't change anything... what the poop? I don't have this problem on another site I work on with the same theme...

This does nothing to the website... any ideas? I even tried changing the theme stylesheet instead of the child theme... still nothing. The website in question is http://comerestministries.com/wordpress/homepage3/

```
/*
Theme Name: Ichthys Child
Theme URI: http://ichthys.modeltheme.com/
Author: ModelTheme
Author URI: http://modeltheme.com/
Description: Ichthys - Church / Nonprofit / Charity WordPress Theme
Template: ichthys
Version: 1.3
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: modeltheme
Tags: fluid-layout, custom-header, custom-menu, featured-images, post-formats, sticky-post

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.

*/
@import url("../ichthys/style.css");

/* =Theme customization starts here
------------------------------------------------------- */

.shop_cart {
    display: none !important;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. For some reason the stylesheet was cached and not clearing when I cleared the cache in the browser. I figured it out when I compared the stylesheet on the browser (after viewing page source) to the stylesheet in the exact same location and file name on the FTP server. I was shocked that they were differnt, but refreshing the stylesheet on the browser fixed it.